# Do I need a transit visa through Italy from Romania to Algeria?

Tags: transit

I hold a Palestinian passport, I entered Romania with Romanian visa multi 90 day, do I need a transit visa to go to Algeria transit through Italy or Spain?

Answer (score 1):

In principle, the Romanian visa should exempt you from any airport transit visa requirement but a Palestinian passport is a bit specific (for obvious political reasons, Palestine cannot be listed as a country in the relevant regulations) so I am not entirely sure which rules apply. You should probably contact the relevant consulate, the airline or the airport to clear things out beforehand.

In any case, this is only true if you stay in the international area of the airport. Otherwise, you might need a Schengen visa.